# Sum over divisors of gcd of two numbers

Tags: number-theory, mobius-inversion, mobius-function

How can I calculate this sum?

$\sum\limits_{d~|~(n_1, n_2)} \mu(d) \tau\left(\dfrac{n_1}{d}\right) \tau\left(\dfrac{n_2}{d}\right)$,

where $(n_1, n_2)$ is gcd of $n_1$ and $n_2$, $\mu$ is Mobius function and $\tau(n)$ is the number of positive divisors of $n$.

I tried to use Mobius inversion formula, but still can't manage to deal with the problem.

Any ideas? Thanks.

P.S. Note that sum in the above equation runs over positive divisors only.

Answer (score 0):

First observe that $S=\sum\limits_{d~|~(n_1, n_2)} \mu(d) \tau\left(\dfrac{n_1}{d}\right) \tau\left(\dfrac{n_2}{d}\right)$ is multiplicative.

Let, $n_1=\prod_{i=1}^{k} p_i^{\alpha_i}\prod_{i=1}^{s}q_i^{\beta_i}$ and$n_2=\prod_{i=1}^{k} p_i^{\delta_i}\prod_{i=1}^{t}r_i^{\gamma_i}$ and $A =\{p_1, p_2,...p_k \}$

So, $S = \prod_{p \in A} ( -\tau\left(\frac{n_1}{p}\right)\tau\left(\frac{n_2}{p}\right) + \tau(n_1)\tau(n_2) )$.

Now, using the fact that $\tau(n)$ is multiplicative.

$S=(\tau(n_1) \tau(n_2))^k \prod_{i=1}^{k}\left( 1-\frac{\alpha_i\delta_i}{(\alpha_i +1)(\delta_i +1)}\right)$

Where k is the number of common prime divisors of $n_1$ and $n_2$

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by saying that S is multiplicative? And could you please explain the 3rd line of your solution -- how did you get this? And what does multiplying over $p \in A$ mean?